# Error adding a user to a group after post confirmation in Cognito

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I have created a userpool in `Cognito`.

What I would like to do is when a new user tries to sign-up using the UI, he gets a verification code. Once the user enters the code, a `Post confirmation` lambda must be triggered and it must add this newly created user directly to a group named `users`.

I found [admin_add_user_to_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_add_user_to_group) client and wrote the following code and deployed it as a lambda:

```
import boto3
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

USER_POOL_ID = ''
CLIENT_ID = ''
CLIENT_SECRET = ''


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    try:
        username = event['username']

        response = client.admin_add_user_to_group(
            UserPoolId=USER_POOL_ID,
            Username=username,
            GroupName='users'
        )
    except client.exceptions.InvalidParameterException:
        return {"error": True, "success": False, "message": "Username doesnt exists"}
        
    except client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
        return {"error": True, "success": False, "message": "Invalid Verification code"}

    except client.exceptions.NotAuthorizedException:
        return {"error": True, "success": False, "message": "User is already confirmed"}

    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": True, "success": False, "message": f"Unknown error {e.__str__()} "}

    return event
```

After deploying the code, I connected it to the `Post confirmation` trigger. Now, when the user tries to sign-up, a code is sent. But, when I paste the code to confirm the user two things happen:

1. The user gets confirmed but,
2. The user isn't added to the `users` group.

It shows the following error:

[image]

What is the mistake that I am committing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post-confirmation has to return the `event`, **always**.

In your code, you are catching errors and then **not** returning the `event`.

So, what happened is that your code caught one of those errors and did not return the event.